# Issue logging into Salesforce Workbench with custom domain

Tags: authentication, workbench

Does anyone know why I receive an 'invalid_grant: authentication failure' message when I try signing into Salesforce Workbench using a custom domain when I can sign into the custom domain normally? I keep getting this error message before being booted back to the login page for Workbench.

[image]

Comment: Please make sure that your profile has "API Enabled" permission.

Comment: Yeah, the custom domain should have nothing to do with login especially if you using oauth. I usually get that when I am logged in as another user and forget to logout. I would check permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I can only use a production account, not a sandbox to access. Must be a permissions issue on my end if this isn't the default behavior. Thanks!